# how to just trigger a powershell script from azure pipeline without waiting for result of script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, allure

I have been tasked to automate test cases using azure pipelines for two applications.
(one is using allure and other is maven).
pipeline uses "PowerShellOnTargetMachines" task to remote into azure windows vm and executes a powershell script containing the test case commands.

since I am using Microsoft hosted agent and these tests run for more than 2 hrs pipeline fails with time limit 60mins.

so I used start-process in the pipeline which will trigger the powershell script in vm as background process and return. no waiting for pipeline. But script is only partially successful doesn't run entire commands.

and for the other application which uses maven all I have to do is run this single command "mvn clean install" which runs test cases and generates reports. running remotely from pipeline is not generating reports properly.

pipeline code:

```
- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
          inputs:
            Machines: '$(machineurl)'
            UserName: '$(username)'
            UserPassword: '$(password)'
            InlineScript: |
                cd <path>
                start-process powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList ". .\allure-report-html.ps1"
```

allure-report-html.ps1 script contains:

```
cd <proj-path>
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o testcasejson "features/main.feature" "features/announcements.feature"
allure generate testcasejson
allure-combine .\allure-report
$sdate = (Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd hh.mm")
$report_path = '<report_path>'
$project_path = '<project_path>' 
Compress-Archive -Path $project_path\$sdate -DestinationPath $report_path\$sdate.zip -Force
```

this works completely fine inside VM using same start-process command. but when running from pipeline I can only see "testcasejson" folder generated from behave command but I can't see "allure-report" folder which will be generated from allure commands.
I just need to trigger a PowerShell script in VM from pipeline without waiting for it to complete.
is there any other method to achieve this